# How to modify a column based on a condition in a time series?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data on animal territories by month (1 = January etc.) for multiple individuals:

```
year month terr_size id
2018  1    20        1 
2018  2    30        1
2019  1    5         1 
2019  2    10        1
2018  3    20        2 
2018  5    25        2
2018  6    20        2
2018  7    20        2 
2019  1    10        2
2019  2    5         2 
2019  3    20        2
2019  4    30        2
```

I want to add a column that has a 1 if two consecutive months exceed some value e.g. 10. One wrinkle is that my data can run over one year for a single id.

```
year month terr_size id new_col
2018  1    20        1  1
2018  2    30        1  1
2019  1    5         1  0 
2019  2    10        1  0
2018  3    20        2  0
2018  5    25        2  1
2018  6    20        2  1
2018  7    20        2  1
2019  1    10        2  0
2019  2    5         2  0
2019  3    20        2  1
2019  4    30        2  1
```

Comment: Is correct to group by year and id and then compute the value you want?

Comment: what about december to january then?

Comment: Yeah I guess that would be necessary and then create the new column based on that grouping. But yes, @Edo that would be an issue. Maybe I need to create a combined year_month column

Comment: Line 5 of your dataframe has month 2 in the first and month 5 in the second one.. just saying..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be expressed compactly using a single left join in a single SQL statement.

Using the input shown in the Note at the end, perform a left self join using the indicated `on` condition and set `new_col` to 1 if for any original row both it and any matched rows have `terr_size` greater than or equal to 10.  If there is no matched row then use coalesce to set `new_col` to 0.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("
  select a.*, 
    coalesce(max(a.terr_size >= 10 and b.terr_size >= 10), 0) 
      new_col
  from DF a 
  left join DF b on 
    a.id = b.id and 
    (12 * b.year + b.month = 12 * a.year + a.month + 1 or
     12 * b.year + b.month = 12 * a.year + a.month - 1)
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
   year month terr_size id new_col
1  2018     1        20  1       1
2  2018     2        30  1       1
3  2019     1         5  1       0
4  2019     2        10  1       0
5  2018     3        20  2       0
6  2018     5        25  2       1
7  2018     6        20  2       1
8  2018     7        20  2       1
9  2019     1        10  2       0
10 2019     2         5  2       0
11 2019     3        20  2       1
12 2019     4        30  2       1
```

### Note

The input and output shown in the question are not consistent so to be clear we assumed this:

```
Lines <- "year month terr_size id
2018  1    20        1  
2018  2    30        1  
2019  1    5         1   
2019  2    10        1  
2018  3    20        2  
2018  5    25        2  
2018  6    20        2  
2018  7    20        2  
2019  1    10        2  
2019  2    5         2  
2019  3    20        2  
2019  4    30        2  "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "year month terr_size id
2018  1    20        1 
2018  2    30        1
2019  1    5         1 
2019  2    10        1
2018  3    20        2 
2018  2    25        2
2018  6    20        2
2018  7    20        2 
2019  1    10        2
2019  2    5         2 
2019  3    20        2
2019  4    30        2  ", header = TRUE)
```

The idea is to create a `date` variable first.
Then you create two copies of your data by changing the dates one month ahead and one month back.

R is efficient memory-wise for this kind of operation, so you won't have a problem.
You will just take the space for one additional column. It doesn't actually replicate the whole dataframe.

Then you can join the new columns to the original dataframe.

You then apply the condition you needed.
I created a `magic_number` variable for that.

At the end, I selected only the original columns plus the one you needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# the threshold number
magic_number <- 10

# creare date variable
df <- df %>% mutate(date = make_date(year, month))

# [p]revious month
dfp <- df %>% transmute(id, date = date - months(1), terr_size_p = terr_size)

# [n]ext month
dfn <- df %>% transmute(id, date = date + months(1), terr_size_n = terr_size)

# join by id and date
df <- df %>% 
    left_join(dfp, by = c("id", "date")) %>% 
    left_join(dfn, by = c("id", "date"))

# for new_col to be 1, terr_size must be over the threshold, so must be at least one between previous and next month
df <- df %>%
    mutate(new_col = as.numeric(terr_size > magic_number & 
            any(terr_size_p > magic_number, terr_size_n > magic_number)))

# remove variables if there is no more use for them
df <- df %>% select(-terr_size_p, -terr_size_n, -date)

df
```

Result:

```
   year month terr_size id new_col
1  2018     1        20  1       1
2  2018     2        30  1       1
3  2019     1         5  1       0
4  2019     2        10  1       0
5  2018     3        20  2       1
6  2018     2        25  2       1
7  2018     6        20  2       1
8  2018     7        20  2       1
9  2019     1        10  2       0
10 2019     2         5  2       0
11 2019     3        20  2       1
12 2019     4        30  2       1
```

(The result is not exactly the same because your initial data and expected results do not correspond at row 5)

This solution handles the december-january issue we talked about in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what is the rule because your output isn't following the rule you talk about (eg: line1/5 doesn't have another month for comparison yet you put an 1, line 6 is separated by 2 months, you put a 1 in the line 11 whereas line12 was <10).

I assumed the most complicated scenario, so you can remove the extra conditions you don't need:

You put an 1 if the territory size remained >10 for two consecutive months including this one (or the first recorded month if it's >10) for each individual.

```
df <- read.table(text = "year month terr_size id
2018  1    20        1 
2018  2    30        1
2019  1    5         1 
2019  2    10        1
2018  3    20        2 
2018  5    25        2
2018  6    20        2
2018  7    20        2 
2019  1    10        2
2019  2    5         2 
2019  3    20        2
2019  4    30        2", header = TRUE)
```

Using dplyr and lag:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(id, year,month) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(newcol=case_when(is.na(lag(month))==TRUE & terr_size>10~1,
                                 lag(id)!=id & terr_size>10~1,
                                 id==lag(id) & year-lag(year)==0  & month-lag(month)==1 & terr_size>10 & lag(terr_size)>10~1,
                                 id==lag(id) & year-lag(year)==1  & lag(month)-month==11 & terr_size>10 & lag(terr_size)>10~1,
                                       TRUE~0))
```

output:

```
   year month terr_size id newcol
1  2018     1        20  1      1
2  2018     2        30  1      1
3  2019     1         5  1      0
4  2019     2        10  1      0
5  2018     3        20  2      1
6  2018     5        25  2      0
7  2018     6        20  2      1
8  2018     7        20  2      1
9  2019     1        10  2      0
10 2019     2         5  2      0
11 2019     3        20  2      0
12 2019     4        30  2      1
```